# Why cannot I have more than 10 concurrent connections to a Postgres RDS database

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

After 10 connections to a Postgres RDS database I start getting error - `Too Many Connections` or `Timed-out waiting to acquire database connection`.

But when I check `max_connections` it shows 405. `pg_roles` shows -1 as `rollconnlimit`. If none of the ceilings are hit why can I not have more than 10 concurrent connections for that user?

Comment: Do you have code that's not closing connections correctly? Any [idle connections](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-max-connections/)?

Comment: I have 1 connection through pgadmin and 9 using psql command line. 10th psql terminal starts throwing this error(11th connection). apart from pgadmin connection(which remains active) all other psql connections go to idle state after I have run the queries in those terminals..

Comment: @AtulOjha Can you check what pg_stat_activity shows?

Comment: What does pg_database.datconnlimit show?  Do you have a connection pooler in front of the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comment from @jjanes on another question gave me a pointer.. the bottleneck was datconnlimit setting from pg_database. Changing it using query below fixed the issue:-

> ALTER DATABASE mydb with CONNECTION LIMIT 50